# Covering space from one UITableView's cell with another one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

The design of the UITableView is something like this:

[image]

I want to make my cells with a tiny triangle, like in a comic book. The thing is, how can i add the triangle to the size of my custom cell? The common rectangle size wouldn't work if i want the user to be able to tap that little rectangle.

And how can i make the opposite? I want the triangle to cover the space of another cell, so tapping the little triangle of the first cell, covering part of the second cell's rectangle space, would activate de first one. This is, substracting a little triangle from the cell's space.

Comment: hmm.. this might be a hack, but we can use two customs row types, alternatively, with them both being rectangular. The first one holds whatever content that needs to be held, and the second just a rectangular image containing the small triangle and that border. clicks can also be handled then.

Comment: or do it so that the triangle isn't really in the other cell, it just appears to be. You would have to hide the normal table border and create a false border. This won't work if you want any of the cells visible content to show in that false space. I suppose another option is to do the whole table yourself, then you can overlap the views. Either way, it may not be that easy to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it would work, but building on user697562's comment, you could try the following:

1. Add a small UIView to the table cell to represent the small triangle
2. Rotate it using its transform property, making sure that, along with its frame, it will have the proper placement.
3. Add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIView
4. Add an instance variable to the view to save the indexPath of the cell it's in (or even the above cell, since it will be associated with the above cell).  This way when the gesture recognizer is triggered, you know what row you're in.
5. Write the action method associated with the gesture recognizer to do the same thing as tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: would do for the above cell.
6. Set the separatorStyle property of the UITableView to UISeparatorStyleNone, so that it won't draw the lines between cells.  If this doesn't work just set the separatorColor property to your table cell's background color.
7. Draw a border along the top & bottom of the cell, accounting for the triangle.

Good luck with it!  Let me know whether it works if you try it.

Comment: It seems like all the pieces are there to do this, and relatively easily. I'd be interested if anyone sees a flaw in the reasoning.